# substring in Java to Substring in C#

Tags: java, c#, substring

I have 2 substring statements in Java that I need to convert to C#. The first of those seems to be working, but the 2nd not so much and I don't know why.

The key is a string of variable length 7-18 characters

First one in Java and then in C#. X can be 1-12 characters.

```
String X = key.substring(0,key.length()-6);
System.out.println("\nX: " + X.toUpperCase());

Console.WriteLine ("\nDLN: " + (key.Substring (0, key.Length - 6).ToUpper ()));
```

2nd one, where Y is the 1st 2 characters after X

```
String Y = key.substring(key.length()-6, key.length()-4);
System.out.println("\nY : " + Y.toUpperCase());

//NOT WORKING    
Console.WriteLine("\nY: " + (key.Substring(key.Length -6, key.Length -4)).ToUpper ());
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Comment: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index and length must refer to a location within the string

Comment: Read the documentation for both methods.  They don't do the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument of [`Substring`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/aka44szs.aspx) is not the index of the last character you want, it's the *number* of characters you want.

So, if you want the first two characters after `X`, use a count of 2.

```
key.Substring(key.Length -6, length: 2)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the documentation for [Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) vs [C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring.aspx), you will find that `C#`'s `Substring` takes a starting index and a length, while Java takes a starting index and ending index.

#### Java

```
substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)
```

#### `C#`

```
Substring(Int32, Int32)     Retrieves a substring from this instance. The substring starts at a specified character position and has a specified length.
```

You seem to be assuming that they take the same arguments.

Comment: Yeah I was because the first one was working correctly

Comment: @user2007843, You need to look at the one with two integer arguments.

Answer (score -1):

In C#, the String.Substring() method's second argument is not the endIndex, as it is in Java, but rather the length of the returned substring. Therefore, you should use this instead:

```
key.Substring(key.Length - 6, 2)
```

Be mindful though that your `key.Length - 6 >= 2`, otherwise, it will throw an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.